# Why are all icon themes showing invalid folder icons

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, icon-themes

A couple days ago, I had ubuntu 17.04, but started experiencing issues with my icons: My file explorer's icons (folders, files, minimize, maximize, close buttons, create new folder button, etc.) and terminal icons had changed to generic looking error icons (white box with gray triangle containing an exclamation point).

So, to fix the issue, I upgraded to 17.10, but the icon issue seems to have worsened, because some of the applications' icons are missing/different/generic.

So, I installed several icon-themes and used `gnu-tweak-tool` to select different themes.  Some of the themes show the correct application icons on the desktop, but none of them show the correct icons for most of the windows I open for almost any application: The minimize, maximize, and other unique/application specific buttons are showing the error-looking icon.  Although it is kind of difficult to see, the screen shot below shows GNOME's Nautilus file manager with several generic icons in the upper far left corner and far right corner:[image]

To fix the issue, here is list of the actions I have taken, based on other forum topics and web tutorials, without success:

- Selected about 20 different icon themes.
- `cp -r /usr/share/icons/ ~/.icons`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall breeze-icon-theme`.  I also tried reinstalling other themes, like `gnome-icon-theme`.
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"`

Here is some info about my computer:

```
uname -or = 4.13.0-16-generic GNU/Linux

cat /etc/lsb-release = DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme = 'Ambiance'
```

I prefer to fix the issue without reinstalling of Ubuntu 17.10 and learn ***why and/or how*** this issue exists.  Although I am a Linux novice, getting under the hood is something I dream about.

Comment: Have you found any answer, I stuck with the same problem without any answer, I have tried everything i found on net but none of them worked for me.

Comment: @NishantBhakta Not yet, still searching.  I even purchased a few books on GTK and the X Window System to learn/understand/fix this, but that approach is going to take a looooong while, because those books are thick.  Hopefully someone who knows  more offers a clue.